# How to open an URL with parameter in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, openurl

if you click for example on someone’s Instagram button from my app 
 you  gonna open the link `instagram://app/` username in the profile

let’s say a user put “mark20” as Instagram username
 You open the link `instagram://app/mark20/`

i want to open instagram with showing 'mark20' . currently it is open Instagram news feeds but not open 'mark20' profile . i want to button click open Instagram  user profile page

For example

[image]

How can i do that

```
func shareToInstagram() {

        //let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://app/")
        //not working anymore 
        let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://app/mark20/")
        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL)) {

            UIApplication.shared.open(instagramURL!, options: ["":""], completionHandler: nil)

        } else {
            print(" Instagram isn't installed ")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: i want to open instagram with showing  'mark20' . currently it is open Instagram news feeds but not showing 'mark20' profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea I  figure  out the problem `path parameter` not working anymore but `query parameter` working

```
func shareToInstagram() {

        let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://user?username=mark20")

        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL)) {


            UIApplication.shared.open(instagramURL!, options: ["":""], completionHandler: nil)

           print("miss you so much ")


        } else {
            print(" Instagram isn't installed ")
        }
    }
```

more check this link [instagram iPhone Hooks](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)

Answer (score 1):

Swift

```
 var instagramAppURL = URL(string: "instagram://user?username=USERNAME")
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramAppURL!) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(instagramAppURL!)
        }
```

Obj C

```
NSURL *instagramAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://user?username=USERNAME"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramAppURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramAppURL];
}
```

First, you have to modify Info.plist to list instagram and facebook with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Simply open Info.plist as a Source Code, and paste this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

For more details and more ways please refer below link
https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/